# Android: How to create a method accesible from all activities and fragments?

Tags: android

I need to create a method that can be called from all activities and all fragments.

Where should I create this ?

Use a static class or an alternative method?

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose or intent of this "method"? Explain what you want to do.

Comment: The intent of the method is store network helpers, for example NetworkAvailable that returns  a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton class which `extends Application`, and call it by `MyApplication.getInstance()`. The `MyApplication` class should be declared in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is if you can be sure you'll only have one of something (it'll keep a reference to the last copy of itself it made) and then declare it static in the constructor.

```
public class MyClass {
    static public MyClass mc;

    public MyClass() {
        this.mc = this;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call, MyClass.mc.function() and everybody can have access to the object.